# Add extra question to Laravel forgotten password form and custom its error messages

Tags: laravel, forgot-password

I'd like to customize the forgotten password form in Laravel.

When asking to reset the password, the user will have to answer a simple question (the name your first pet, the name of your childhood best friend, etc) besides inserting his/her email. This is to avoid other people asking password reset if they know the account's email, but are not the owner of the account.

I also would like to custom the errors messages to, actually, not show errors. For example, if an invalid email is inserted, it would not show the error message "We can't find a user with that e-mail address." I don't like it because someone may guess the email of a user by trying different emails until she/he stops getting the error message. Instead, I would like to show the message "If the information provided is correct, you will receive an email with the link to reset your password."

How to add these functionalities to Laravel auth?

I am looking for a solution that I don't have to create an entire login system from scratch (I think that if I try to design everything from scratch I'd probably miss something and create security vulnerabilities). I'd like to keep the Laravel auth system and just add these two features.

Feel free to suggest other ways to achieve the desired result and to make my question clearer. I'll appreciate that.

Comment: You can try to modify `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php` and `resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php`. If you have any error you can open a question showing the code you tried.

Comment: And what if they forgot the secret question? ;)

Comment: "This is to avoid other people asking password reset if they know the account's email, but are not the owner of the account." Why do you care about this? Is it actually happening, or are you going to all this extra trouble on the assumption that it might?

Comment: I'm going to all this extra trouble on the assumption it might happen :) hahaha

Comment: @rits I suppose they won't forget the secret question. If they forget it and they complain, then I will remove the extra question and go back to the previous auth system. It is supposed to be an easy question (like, who was your best childhood friend? who would forget that?), so I suppose nobody will forget the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is you don't need to rewrite everything.

The bad news is, you need to understand traits and how to extend/override them, which can be a little confusing.

The default controller that Laravel creates `ForgotPasswordController` doesn't do much. Everything it does is in the trait. The trait `SendsPasswordResetEmails` contains a few methods, most importantly for the validation in `validateEmail` method.

You can override this `validateEmail` method with one that checks for an answered question. You override traits by altering the 'use' statement.

For example change;

```
use SendsPasswordResetEmails
```

to:

```
use SendsPasswordResetEmails {
    validateEmail as originValidateEmail
}
```

This will tell the code to re-name the original method `validateEmail` to `originValidateEmail` allowing you to create a new `validateEmail` in your own `ForgotPasswordController`.

You can then, inside `ForgotPasswordController` add a replacement which will be called by the default reset password code:

```
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    // add in your own validation rules, etc.
    $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email', 'questionfield' => 'required']);
}
```

To alter the error message, you can simply edit the language file found in `resources/lang/en/passwords.php`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I was able to accomplish it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the user @Darryl E. Clarke, I managed to solve the problem. Here is what I did:

Add this line at the top of the file `ForgotPasswordController`, after namespace:

```
use App\User;
```

Add these 3 methods in the same file:

```
    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateRequest($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Regardless if that
        // worked, we will send the same response. We won't display error messages
        // That is because we do not want people guessing the users' email. If we
        // send an error message telling that the email is wrong, then a malicious
        // person may guess a user' email by trying until he/she stops getting that
        // error message.

        $user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();

        if ($user == null) {
            return $this->sendResponse();
        }

        if ($user->secrete_question != $request->secrete_question) {
            return $this->sendResponse();
        }

        $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );

        return $this->sendResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Validate the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email', 'secrete_question' => 'required|string']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResponse()
    {
        $response = 'If the information provided is correct, you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.';
        return back()->with('status', $response);
    }
```

Customize it the way you want.

Hope that it will helps others!!

Comment: Actually, I thought that had worked, but it didn't. If I am able to solve this I will update the answer

Comment: Now it worked! I updated the answer and it is correct!